# I want to get zone time from NSDate for calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to get zone time from date and even i searched a lot for this but didn't
      found any thing related to my requirement.Bellow is my code -

```
  NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit)fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
```

Output of d = 2014-05-31 16:00:00 +0000

My requirement is = 16:00:00 +0000

I want to slit d's data and get "16:00:00 +0000" into string variable to handle timezone as per coutry.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Well... I was trying to close this a duplciate and marked it as a dupe of something it's not, so I had to retract... but this is a pretty common `NSDateFormatter` question.

Comment: Good luck!  There is no timezone in an NSDate -- the timezone must be specified when you format the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSDateFormatter. Something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
```

If you'll be using this code several times, consider caching the date formatter, because it is expensive to create it every time.

Comment: I tried your code but in result i am getting null value . I already tried bellow code but it's not splitting date even concatenating default date.My code was -  NSString *str1=@"00:00:00 +0000";
    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [form setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date1= [form dateFromString:str1];